# What is the best way to detect memory leak in go micro service running on production

Tags: go, memory-leaks, pprof

I need to know some efficient way / tools in golang that will help us to detect memory leak in the micro service that is live and running on production

Comment: Can you please your findings and conclusion when you searched this topic on google ?

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is to compare 2 heap pprofs. You can do it like this:

- Extract a heap profile heap0.pprof
- Add some load to the application
- Extract another heap profile heap1.pprof
- Compare them with go tool pprof -base heap0.pprof  heap1.pprof

This way you can see exactly what is increasing over time.